# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have dataframe and I need to make an assessment of the quality before using nearest neighbor method.
I use `sklearn.cross_validation.KFold`, but I don't know, how can I give a dataframe to this function.

```
quality = KFold(df, n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

But it return

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to pass the number of rows you want to perform the split on:

```
quality = KFold(len(df), n_folds=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

this will use the number of rows of the df and return you an array of indices to perform the splits on, you can then use this to slice the df:

```
for train_index, test_index in quality:
    # do something with slices
    df.iloc[train_index]
    df.iloc[test_index]
```

if your df index is an int64 index and is monotonic and increases from `0` then you can use `loc` instead of `iloc`